# Duplicating certain rows while retaining variable values (except for 1 cell)

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

I am using Excel. I have a dataset which consists of a number of variables. Sadly this dataset was entered by multiple people who didn't keep to the same format. So I have a dataset containing data with multiple formats that looks as follows:

```
Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4   Var5 ...
 x      x      X1     X2     x   ...
```

The problem here is Var3 and Var4. They both contain info meant for multiple rows. Let's start with Var3. This is supposed to contain a single number, however sometimes it has been entered as 4+2 which means there should be two rows instead of one which are identical. Save that one contains Var3=4 and one Var3=2. What is more, this data has been entered with the following formats: x+x; x+x+x+...

Additionally, sometimes the sex of an individual was included and the data was written as 2f2m or 1m+x, where f/m denote sex (which for now I wish to ignore). Meaning 2f2m should read as 4 instead and 1m+1 should read as 2 entries with the Var3=1 each.

As for Var4, usually this one is not a problem, but in some cases this info needs to be split into multiple rows as well, alongside the values from Var3. For example, if Var3=2+1 and Var4=2OL1R then what I would need is 2 rows. One with Var3=2 Var4=OL and 1 with Var3=1 Var=R. Though this second problem is of less importance for now.

[image: An example of the different ways in which Var3 has been entered, and what the data looks like]

My experience with Excel data manipulation is limited. Usually I would use R, although even then I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Could someone point me in the right direction? I'm not sure which terms/functions I should look for.

Comment: I've added a short image of a sample of the data (somewhat edited). I hope this clarifies the issue as I find it difficult to put in text. Thank you for your edits.

Comment: It would be helpful to also have a screencap of the desired result and what you have tried so far

Comment: How many rows are you talking about? Is this a one time data cleanup or will you be collecting additional data. I believe this data cleansing exercise will be best handled manually, unless you can write VBA code that anticipates all of the different scenarios. The takeaway from this is to train the personnel entering the data...

Comment: select 1st row, Data>Apply filter. Then use filter to 'shortlist' the problematic row. Then you may edit it at multiple row at one go.. or use and extra column to 'mark' it (and work on it later). | Since the error pattern introduced is quite consistent, replace multiple row value at once seems to be a practical solution.

Comment: It is indeed a one time cleanup, but of thousands of rows. Sadly not my personnel but good advice in general. As I have never worked with VBA I did not really know how to start with this. I have now contacted a colleague who thinks he can solve it using phyton. Thank you for all the suggestions. Due to the large number of data even using a shortlist will take a considerable amount of time (There is a large number of variability) but it does indeed offer an easier solution than fixing it all by hand. If all else fails I will give this a shot. Thank you.